# Unit testing a controller that invokes a method that checks the DOM for a property

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs

I am writing a unit test for a controller where somewhere in the workflow checks the DOM for a specific property. Currently I am just mocking the method via

```
spyOn(controller, 'methodChecksDom').return('value that I want').
```

Works fine but how do I make the test pass without mocking that method. I've tried using $document and actually inserting dom via

```
$document.find('body').append('<div>...</div>')
```

but I get the following error in my test:

Error: Dirty test! DOM residue found in document body: ...
        at Error (native)

What is the proper way of doing this. Testing the method without mocking it. Many Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this is not the case, but doing DOM stuff in controllers is not recommended at all, testings is one of the problems :P

Comment: You're correct. I am not doing any DOM manipulations but you're correct..is this an issue even if I use the $document service? Is it safe to say that it is unwise to $document in controllers because of testing difficulties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're dead set on testing the DOM directly here, you need to clean up the inserted element after the test. That's why you're getting an error--you're not cleaning up the thing you inserted via `$document`.

That being said, you *really* should not be even so much as reading the DOM inside of a controller.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Didn't realize that reading the  DOM from the controller was such a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

You should do any DOM manipulation or adding of behaviors by using a custom directive.

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

```
angular.module("myApp",[]).directive("mydirective",function(){
  return {
    link: function(scope,iElem,iAttrs) {
       //Do stuff per instance here
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I am not doing any dom manipulation but simply checking a property of an element. e.g $('#someId').attr('id') How do I make that 'id' property available to the controller?